# Is the universal representation an order isomorphism?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a  Banach *-algebra. By a *-representations of $A$, we mean a *-homomorphism  $\pi:A\to B(H_\pi)$, where $B(H_\pi)$ is the space of all bounded linear maps on a Hilbert space $H_\pi$. Let $\pi_u=\oplus_{\pi\in Rep(A)}\pi.$

> Q. Suppose that $\ker \pi_u=0$. Is $\pi_u$ an order isomorphism? (that is $x\geq0$ iff $\pi_u(x)\geq0$).

Remark. For  a given self-adjoint element $x$ in $A$ we write $x\geq0$ if $x=\sum_1^n a^*_ia_i$  where $a_i\in A$ and $n$ is a natural number.